# Vue reducing bundle size of fusioncharts and apexcharts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fusioncharts, apexcharts

I try to reduce my vue bundle size by changing the import of vue-apexcharts and vue-fusioncharts.

this is the import of apexcharts:

```
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts';

components: {
        apexchart: VueApexCharts,
    },
```

But I only use two type of charts.

And for fusioncharts:

```
import VueFusionCharts from 'vue-fusioncharts';
import FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import Widgets from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.widgets';
import FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';

Widgets(FusionCharts);
FusionTheme(FusionCharts);
Vue.use(VueFusionCharts, FusionCharts);
```

I only use it for one chart "hbullet" and it import all the library.

[fusioncharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylBYW.png)
[apexcharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwiJG.png)

Vue version 2.6.12

Did any one know how I can import only the charts that I want to use and not all library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use modular import with FusionCharts, here is a snippet below

```
import VueFusionCharts from 'vue-fusioncharts';
import FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts/core';
import hbullet from 'fusioncharts/viz/hbullet';

// register VueFusionCharts component
Vue.use(VueFusionCharts, FusionCharts, hbullet);
```

Please note this will not work for older browsers like IE